# How to change size of ALL icons/folders in Finder?

Tags: finder, folders, icon

I only know about this:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder DesktopViewOptions -dict IconSize -integer 188x188px.; killall Finder’
```

But it’s only for the Desktop…

Answer (score 8):

Open a Finder window in Icon mode (⌘1), then click **Show View Options** (in the View menu, or ⌘J). Make the changes you want, then click the **Use as Defaults** button at the bottom of the panel to make it stick for all folders.

[image: Finder View Options]

Comment: I am trying this for list view. It didnt work for me.
I did it in one folder. But then it shows same size on other folders.

Answer (score 0):

How about *Finder > View > Show View Options > Icon Size*?

(I'm not 100% sure about the naming as I don't have a Mac currently with me...)