# Missing "Use as Defaults" box in "Show View Options"

Tags: macos, finder, preferences

I am trying to change the default size of my icons and their grid spacing as was asked in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/68674/250408). For whatever reason, my Mac does not have a **Use as Defaults** box in **Show View Options**. Do you have any idea why it doesn't or what, if anything, I can do to make it so it does?

I checked the answer given to [this similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/89525/250408), but believe I am already in the correct view, as evidenced below. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

[image]

Comment: Try on a non-dynamic folder such as Downloads or Documents.  The 'All My Files" is a dynamic type of folder that changes contents much like a Smart Folder.

Answer (score 3):

All My Files isn't a folder, it's a special view in Finder. Navigate to a real folder such as your Documents folder and the View Options window will show a Use as Defaults button then.

Comment: The reported problem though applies to regular folders as well (High Sierra 10.13.6)